# Make div start at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the test image of my website. Currently the block at the top gets larger as you scroll down the screen but it comes from the top. How do I get it to come up from the bottom? Is it to do with offset? The `div` is called `stem` and the bottom `div` is called `timeline`.

[image]

```js
function showStem() {
  var stemb = $(".stem-background");
  var stem = $(".stem");
  var timeline = $(".timeline");
  var timelineot = timeline.offset().top;
  var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > timelineot - h) {
      stemb.hide();
      stem.show();
      stem.height(scroll + h - timelineot);
    } else {
      stemb.hide();
      stem.hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.timeline {
    background: #112C30;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #B9CFD0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.timeline a {
    color: #B9CFD0;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B9CFD0;
}

.timeline h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

.main-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.main-content .section-inner, .main-content .post-wrapper {
    *zoom: 1;
}

.main-content .section-inner:before, .main-content .section-inner:after, .main-content .post-wrapper:before, .main-content .post-wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.main-content .section-inner:after, .main-content .post-wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
}

.section .section-inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
}

@media only screen {
    .section .section-inner {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 1024px;
    }
}


.stem-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: auto;

}


.stem-wrapper.color-yellow .stem-background {
    background: #E9E566;
}

.stem-wrapper.color-green .stem-background {
    background: #35C189;
}

.stem-wrapper.color-white .stem-background {
    background: #FFF;
}

.stem-wrapper .stem, .stem-wrapper .stem-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -30px;
    width: 60px;
}

.stem-wrapper .stem{
    background: #1e4f56;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

.stem-wrapper .stem-background {
    background: #ecf6f9;
    height: 50%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="stem-wrapper">
    <div class="stem"></div>
    <div class="stem-background"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- more content -->
</div>
```

I have tried a few things in CSS but a lot of the overflows are redundant.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I got an answer finally!

Comment: @rule I got an answer finally!

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer I was looking for

```
stem.offset({top:timelineot});
```

Tested it by `timelineot+50` and `timelineot-50`